# Decision tree always returns perfect accuarcy

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree, cross-validation

Working with a decision tree and using cross validation; I am recreating the tree n times to look for the best depth, but at every depth level (1-20) i am returning 100% accuracy despite splitting the training data via cross validation and changing the tree depth to try and avoid over fitting.  The code is below with the data found here, https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Mammographic+Mass

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold

features = ['birad','age','Shape','margin','density','severity']

df = pd.read_csv('mammographic_masses.data',header=None,names=features)

df= df[df.birad != '?']
df= df[df.age != '?']
df= df[df.Shape != '?']
df= df[df.margin != '?']
df= df[df.density != '?']

x = df[features][:-1]
y = df['severity'][:-1]

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.4,random_state=0)

depth = []
best_depth = 3
best_score = 0
for i in range(1,20):
  clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=i)
  clf = clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
  scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf,x_train,y_train,cv=10)
  ascore = clf.score(x_test,y_test)
  #print "DEPTH = ",i
  #print "PSCORES = ",sum(scores)/float(len(scores))
  #print "ASCORE = ",ascore
  #print
  depth.append((i,clf.score(x_test,y_test)))
  if ascore > best_score:
        best_score,best_depth = ascore,i
print best_depth,' ',best_score
```

Comment: it seems that your 'x' contains label (severity)

Answer (score 0):

Found an error in my code that resolved this issue. What I had written was

```
x = df[features][:-1]
```

but what I should have written was,

```
x = df[features[:-1]]
```

In other words my input was including the target/results col, which is why I had been obtaining perfect accuracy.

Comment: Why it was marked as -1? It is a
 good question. I was stuck on it for hours. Author took time to answer to help other people searching for this answer.